# How to get Google-Sign in to work after getting error 10?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-signin

I have trying to implement Google Sign In on my app by following the guide.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#add_google_play_services

However, I keep getting error 10 everytime I go to try to log in and I know it means its a developer error but, I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. I implemented all the code, made sure I have the correct packages and updated Android Studio.

I tried different client ids from SHA1 hashes that came from multiple generated signed bundles and apks for my app. I tried the pre generated one that Google gives you for sign-in. Any ideas?

Intent for google sign in

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                .build();

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getActivity(),gso);

        Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 21);
```

OnActivityResult function

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 21) {

        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data); 
     handleSignInResult(task);

    }

    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        Log.d("frag", "intent fired and something went wrong");

    }
}
```

handleSignInResult function

```
    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.

        Log.d("frag", "Email of account is " + account.getEmail());

    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w("ytsignin", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the SHA-1 code and package name in developer console. Most of the time it is what causes the error 10 which is 'DEVELOPER_ERROR'.
Check the SHA-1 in console against the one you get from Android Studio after running signingReport.[image]